# Проблема с AIOPG.SA пример из aiohttpdemo_polls

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, asyncio, aiohttp

Всем доброго дня!

Изучая документацию aiohttp, на примере https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp-demos/tree/master/demos/polls/aiohttpdemo_polls, переписывая ее полностью(за исключением описания таблицы) столкнулся с проблемой:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В чем проблема? Python 3.8, AIOHTTP 3.6.2 AIOPG 1.0

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Answer (score 0):

После импорта `asyncio` смени имплементацию Event Loop:

```
asyncio.set_event_loop_policy(asyncio.WindowsSelectorEventLoopPolicy())
```

Comment: Работает! У меня просто нет слов.. Убил весь день на это. Это мой первый вопрос на SO и через 3 минуты я получаю ответ, решающий мою проблему...Спасибо! 

На самом деле странная ситуация, пару часов моих поисков назад я наткнулся на совет о том, что наоборот нужно использовать windows protector event loop, само собой не заработало. asyncio становится все интересней )

Еще раз спасибо!

Comment: Рад был помочь! Многие `aio*`-либы работают только с `SelectorEventLoop` и до Python 3.8 все было ок т.к. по дефолту на всех ОС включалась `SelectorEventLoop`. но в 3.8 было решено сменить дефолтную имплементацию на `ProactorEventLoop` на винде, отсюда все беды. Для референса: [bpo 34687](https://bugs.python.org/issue34687), добавивший это изменение.

Comment: Если ответ решил вопрос, то отметь его как правильный (серая галка под количеством голосов), см. [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)